# Nginx, Nuxt, Laravel, Simulacro deploy en /etc/nginx/sites-available

Tags: laravel, nginx, pm2, nuxt

Estoy intentando hacer un simulacro de deploy en local. Tengo el frontend con Nuxt 2, backend con Laravel.

Tengo corriendo el front con pm2 sobre el puerto 3000 y con nginx y el archivo hosts lo estoy accediendo desde el dominio aplicacion.test. Hasta ahí todo bien.
Tengo levantado el backend sobre el puerto 8000 con sail (en en el server será solo nginx, es solo para probar).

El archivo default de la carpeta /etc/nginx/sites-available me quedó así.

```
server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  aplicacion.test;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;    
    }
}

server {
    listen   80;
    server_name  api.aplicacion.test;
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
        include /etc/nginx/proxy_params;   
    }
}
```

Trato de acceder a api.aplicacion.test y no redirecciona, qué hago mal? je

Comment: tienes acceso al front?

Comment: sí, desde aplicacion.test